# How do I get some string from a text input using PHP?

Tags: php, html

How do I get the the value from an input text box using PHP? My code is below:

```
<body>
    <form action="new.php" method="post">
        Date: <input name="date" type="text" value="Saturday, October 11, 2014" />
              <input name="ok" type="submit" value="Submit" />
     <?php      
        if(isset($_POST['ok'])){
            $day=$_POST['date'];
            echo "today's date is".$day;//how do I echo only the word Saturday?
        }else   
    ?>
    </form>
</body>
```

I would like to `echo` only the word "Saturday", but I am unsure of how to do this given that my `$day` variable contains the entire date string. Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming

Comment: Do you already know how to access submitted form input? http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php

Comment: thank you @micheal now i know how to get it

Comment: by the way @micheal the link you given was getting the whole value of the text box what i want here is only some part of the string not the whole value of the textbox

Comment: Which part of the value do you want get ?

Comment: @Mubo i want only the word "Saturday"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *explode* function:

```
<body>
<form action="new.php" method="post">
    Date: <input name="date" type="text" value="Saturday, October 11, 2014" />
          <input name="ok" type="submit" value="Submit" />
 <?php      
    if(isset($_POST['ok'])){
        $day=$_POST['date'];
        $pieces = explode(",", $day);
        echo "today's date is ".$pieces[0]; // show only word "Saturday"
    }else   
?>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

YOU can get any data from form by super global var: $_POST['name_of _input'] IF YOU make method post or $_GET['name_of_input'] if you make method get.
this html tags

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="name_of_page_process.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="days" placeholder="enter name of day" />
<input type="submit" name="sub" />
</form>
</body>
</html>



    this code of process by php :

<?php 
if(isset($_post['sub'])){
$day=$_post['days'];
echo "name of day is".$day;

}

?>
```

Comment: i want only one word from the text box, @hamdy

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
<body>
    <form action="" method="get">
        Date: <input type="text" name='day' value="Saturday, October 1<?php ?>1, 2014" />
<input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>


<?php  


     $day = $_GET["day"] ;
     if(isset($day)):
     echo strtok($day, ",");

     endif;   


?>
```